# How to build a jar file from clojure source code on Windows XP

Tags: jar, clojure

Could you please tell how to build a jar file from clojure source code on window xp,
Wihout using maven or such software? Only clojure and Windows XP

Comment: @skuro.                                                                  I am getting this output on                                       "java -cp clojure.jar:classes:src".Please help!                     as visible-> test-Clojure contains classes, src directory, src directory contains example.clj file. test-Clojure directory contains clojure.jar.

output- >

D:\work\test-Clojure>java -cp clojure.jar:classes:src Usage: java [-options] class [args...] (to execute a class) or java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...] (to execute a jar file)

Comment: Seems like the [win32 version](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) of the `java` tool has different syntax for [setting the classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html). I'll update my post.

Comment: D:\work\test-Clojure>java -cp clojure.jar;classes;src
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any tool, you're bound to do some quirky steps manually. Say you have `clojure.jar` in the current directory, along with a target folder for compilation named `classes` and a clojure source file in `src/awesome.clj` with the following code:

```
(ns awesome)

(defn life-universe-and-everything []
  (println "42"))
```

In order to compile it you will issue the following commands on the command line:

EDIT: use semicolon instead of colon to separate classpath elements in Windows environments

```
java -cp clojure.jar;classes;src clojure.main
Clojure 1.3.0
user=> (compile 'awesome)
```

This will produce the compiled classes into the `classes` folder. Please note that if your code depends on any library, you need to adapt the `-cp` parameter values when starting the JVM.

Than, you will create the JAR file using:

```
jar cvf awesome.jar -C classes .
```

Finally, to call your function:

```
java -cp clojure.jar;awesome.jar clojure.main -e "(use 'awesome) (life-universe-and-everything)"
```

I'd also advise you to read the [official documentation](http://clojure.org/repl_and_main).

Comment: I am getting this output on "java -cp clojure.jar:classes:src".Please help! as visible-> test-Clojure contains classes, src directory, src directory contains example.clj file. test-Clojure directory contains clojure.jar. output- > D:\work\test-Clojure>java -cp clojure.jar:classes:src Usage: java [-options] class [args...] (to execute a class) or java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...] (to execute a jar file)

Comment: /sathya                                                                                  D:\work\test-Clojure>java -cp clojure.jar;classes;src
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)                                      **i am gettingthis output. cmd is askingto include some of these options! Its not working!!

Comment: I'm sorry, cut'n'paste issue here. I forgot to include the class you need to invoke, `clojure.main`, which starts a REPL. `java` simply didn't know what to do after loading the classpath..

Comment: i am getting 3 class files in classes directory. Is it fine? what does -C means while creating jar file.

Comment: Yes, you're effectively compiling your Clojure code. `-C dir` tells `jar` that `dir` is the base path for its operations. In our case, it's first looking at `classes` then resolving `.` to be that folder, hence including all of its content into the JAR.

Comment: and how to run this jar file?

Comment: can you tell how to run now? using this jar file?

Comment: I updated my post to answer your last question. Please be aware that there are several other possibilities to execute your clojure code, e.g. [`gen-class`](http://clojure.org/compilation) to create a Java class with a `main` method.

Comment: can you also explain little about other option in link provided. like __-i, -r, -h__ etc