# Clojure compilation and running with cygwin

Tags: java, clojure

compiling clojure files generate .class files in *classes directory*. Since classes direct is child to current directory so for running a java program which is calling clojure will be *javac -cp classes CalculateSum.java*. How to run ?? *java CalculateSum* isn't possible since class files are in child directory *classes*. java -cp classes CalculateSum isn't working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658928/how-to-build-a-jar-file-from-clojure-source-code-on-windows-xp


check out this for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile by javac

```
>dir /d /b
chapter_2

>dir /b chapter_2
CalculateSum.java

>javac chapter_2/CalculateSum.java

>dir /b chapter_2
CalculateSum.class
CalculateSum.java
```

clojure execute command ex.)

```
java -cp .;lib;lib/jline-1.0.jar;lib/clojure.jar;lib/clojure-contrib-1.2.0.jar jline.ConsoleRunner clojure.main
```

move chapter_2 directory to under lib

DEMO:

```
Clojure 1.2.1
user=> (import 'chapter_2.CalculateSum)
chapter_2.CalculateSum
user=> (. CalculateSum main (make-array String 0))
Enter first number to add:
2.3
Enter second number to add:
4.5
2.3 + 4.5 = 6.8
nil
```