# CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve classname: Carro, compiling:(carro/car.clj:6)

Tags: jar, clojure, compiler-errors, illegalargumentexception

So.. I have this problem (the one in the title). Just to give a background about what I did:
Create a Java class called Carro:

```
public class Carro{
  public Carro(){}
  public void turnon(String sound){
     System.out.println(sound);
  }
}
```

I've compile it:

```
javac Carro.java
```

And created a .jar:

```
jar -cf Carro.jar Carro.class
```

So, I created a new lein project:
lein new test

Created a /lib directory and pasted the Carro.jar in it.

Create a folder called carro in `test/src/` directory and create a .clj file, called `car.clj`:

```
(ns carro.car
  (:import [Carro] )
)

(defn callCarro [] 
  (let [car (new Carro)]
     (.turnon "vruuum!" car)
  )
)
```

After all of that, I edited the project.clj file and add a :import [Carro] after the last parenthesis.

So, when I run the project using `lein repl`, I get this error:

```
    $ lein repl
    user=> (require 'carr.car :reload)
    CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Unable to resolve classname: Carro, compiling:(carro/car.clj:6)
```

Any ideas to solve this... Problem?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8402860/1183294) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14014153/1183294) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leiningen 2 relies on maven to manage dependencies. Version 1 used to copy jars to the lib directory but this behavior was removed (see https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/FAQ.md). If you need a certain jar for your project, the easiest way is to install that jar on your local maven repo and let leiningen do the rest.

Maven (and so leiningen) needs a version, a group and an artifact for the jar you are working with (see https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#artifact-ids-groups-and-versions). So our first step will be to rename Carro.jar to Carro-0.1.0.jar. To make things a little easier, lets use a leiningen plugin to do the rest. Add the `lein-localrepo` plugin to your project.clj, something like:

```
(defproject foo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-localrepo "0.4.1"]])
```

Then you can ask leiningen for the coordinates of the Carro dependency:

```
$ lein localrepo coords Carro-0.1.0.jar
Carro-0.1.0.jar Carro/Carro 0.1.0
```

That last part is the info needed to install to the mvn repo:

```
$ lein localrepo install Carro-0.1.0.jar Carro/Carro 0.1.0
```

After that,the jar is installed in your mvn repository: `~/.m2/repository/Carro/Carro/0.1.0/Carro-0.1.0.jar`. So finally, add the newly installed dependency to project.clj:

```
(defproject foo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [Carro/Carro "0.1.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-localrepo "0.4.1"]])
```

And then from the repl:

```
$ lein repl
user=> (new Carro)
#<Carro Carro@7c04703c>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there may be multiple causes:

- Clojure has trouble loading classes without a package which causes this.
- that is not the typical location for test classes if you are using Leiningen
- If you didn't run `(import 'Classname)` from the repl you will need to do that as well.